# AttributeError: 'ballcl' object has no attribute 'ballX'

Tags: python, class, object, pygame, attributes

I'm creating a Pong game as a fun project to learn python and pygame. I am currently having an issue, mentioned above.  Please ignore my slop that is code lol. The relevant code:

```
ballVelX = 5
ballVelY = 5
ballWidth = 15
ballHeight = 15
ballX = 450
ballY = 300

class ballcl:
    def __init(self, ballX, ballY, ballVelX, ballVelY, ballWidth, ballHeight):
        self.ballX = ballX
        self.ballY = ballY
        self.ballVelX = ballVelX
        self.ballVelY = ballVelY
        self.ballWidth = ballWidth
        self.ballHeight = ballHeight

    def ball(self):
        ball = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [self.ballX, self.ballY, self.ballWidth, self.ballHeight])

        ball
        #ball movement
        self.ballX += self.ballVelX

ballOb = ballcl()
gameRunning = True

while gameRunning:

    ballOb.ball()
```

The error i receive is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Ping/Main.py", line 67, in <module>
    ballOb.ball()
  File "d:/Ping/Main.py", line 49, in ball
    ball = pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [self.ballX, self.ballY, self.ballWidth, self.ballHeight])
AttributeError: 'ballcl' object has no attribute 'ballX'
```

Comment: The method name should be **`__init__`** not  `__init`.

Comment: @PedramParsian Duh, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

See [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). The name of the constructor of a class is `__init__` rather than `__init`:

```py
class ballcl:
    def __init__(self, ballX, ballY, ballVelX, ballVelY, ballWidth, ballHeight):
        # [...]
```